# Count unique values in second column corresponding to unique value in first column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have a Google sheet with cities corresponding to countries like this. Notice that neither countries nor cities are unique and there can be duplicates.

```
|    A    |      B     |
------------------------
| UK      | London     |
| UK      | Manchester |
| UK      | Manchester |
| UK      | Birmingham |
| Ireland | Dublin     |
| Norway  | Oslo       |
| Norway  | Trondheim  |
```

Now I want to count the number of unique cities for each unique country. The result should look like this.

```
|    C    | D |
---------------
| UK      | 3 |
| Ireland | 1 |
| Norway  | 2 |
```

I got column `C` using `UNIQUE(A1:A)`. But how do I get column `D`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE(A1:B), 
 "select Col1,count(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1
  label count(Col2)''", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C:C, QUERY(UNIQUE(A1:B), 
 "select Col1,count(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1
  label count(Col2)''", 0), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks, however this only works if I take column C from the query itself. If column C is already provided and I select only the output column D from the query, the order might have been mixed up so that the columns don't match anymore. You can try it yourself by writing only [..] select count(Col2) where [..].

Comment: @philmcole answer updated